# Verify the email in wordpress comments. Functions

Tags: wordpress

I want to verify the email in WordPress comments. Send mail to commenting. The commenter check your mail with one click. Then post the message automatically. I have no idea how to write the function.

Comment: Hi, this is Off Topic on Stack Overflow, as we expect questions to be about speficic technical issues. Take a look at the WP plugin repository: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ you may find what you need there.

Comment: I edited the question.I think now is better.

Comment: OP is my function what you're looking for? your question is a bit vague to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckEmail(email)
{
   if(email contains text before @ && text between @ and . && text after the .)
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: Yes, now I have to think how to implement it .Good answer .

Comment: This doesn't seem to fulfill the OP's requirements though. He wants to confirm the E-Mail address by sending the commenter an actual E-Mail

Comment: hint: use the Split() function

Comment: That will be alot more catchy.

Comment: I want to have correct email in the comments.For email verify and accept TOS .To send newsletter. It's a bit complex .And without any line of code .And with my bad English , it would be better to close the issue .Sorry.

Comment: Without coding it is very difficult. Adventually you need scripts/plugins to make it work because everything is based on scripts.